# Flutter painter draw arc with indication when passing 360 degrees

Tags: flutter, drawing

I want to draw an arc, ranging from 0 degrees to 360 degrees **and beyond**.
When passing 360 degrees, I want to indicate the user in some way, maybe with a gap, or some shadow (see attached image, especially the 360 and 450 sample).
Currently, there's no indication (bottom left corner of the image).

[image]

Currently I'm drawing the ring like this:

```
// full paint
Paint full = Paint()
  ..color = fullColor
  ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
  ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
  ..strokeWidth = _strokeWidth;

// full
double arcAngle = 2 * pi * (fullPercent / 100);
canvas.drawArc(Rect.fromCircle(center: center, radius: _radius), -pi / 2,
    arcAngle, false, full);
```

How can I achieve such ring style?

UPDATE (solved based on moneer's answer):

```
// empty
final Offset center = Offset(0.5 * size.width, 0.5 * size.height);
canvas.drawCircle(center, _radius, empty);

double arcAngleStart = -0.5 * pi;
double arcAngleEnd = 2 * pi * (percent % 100 / 100);
if (percent >= 100) {
  // full
  canvas.drawCircle(center, _radius, full);
  // over
  canvas.drawArc(Rect.fromCircle(center: center, radius: _radius),
      arcAngleStart, arcAngleEnd + 0.0 * pi / 180, false, over);
  // arcAngleStart & arcAngleEnd
  arcAngleStart -= 0.25 * pi;
  arcAngleEnd += 0.25 * pi;
}

// full
canvas.drawArc(Rect.fromCircle(center: center, radius: _radius),
    arcAngleStart, arcAngleEnd, false, full);
```

Comment: can you attach a snapshot of what you have achieved?

Comment: Sure, in the attached image: left 4 rings (90, 270, 360, 450)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the gap by drawing multiple layers. You will most likely need to do this anyways (in order to draw the background) unless you come up with a different approach. Here is a sample using  your code. Excuse the messiness. I'm in a bit of a hurry :)

```
   Paint background = Paint()
  ..color = Colors.red
  ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
  ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
  ..strokeWidth = 10.0;
    
    Paint middle = Paint()
  ..color = Colors.white
  ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
  ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
  ..strokeWidth = 10.0;
    
    Paint full = Paint()
  ..color = Colors.red
  ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
  ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
  ..strokeWidth = 10.0;

    
    double arcAngle1 = 2 * pi * (100 / 100);
canvas.drawArc(Rect.fromCircle(center: Offset(size.height + 100, size.width + 100), radius: 50), -pi / 2,
    arcAngle1, false, background);
    
        double arcAngle2 = 2 * pi * (51 / 100);
canvas.drawArc(Rect.fromCircle(center: Offset(size.height + 100, size.width + 100), radius: 50), -pi / 2,
    arcAngle2, false, middle);
    
double arcAngle3 = 2 * pi * (50 / 100);
canvas.drawArc(Rect.fromCircle(center: Offset(size.height + 100, size.width + 100), radius: 50), -pi / 2,
    arcAngle3, false, full);
```

You will need to add conditions based on parameters passed to control what is being drawn. So for example if you need no indication just draw a full circle with a single color.